# Convergence of Sum of reciprical of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F(n)$ be the n'th Fibonacci number, How to show:
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F(k)}$ converges

Ratio test converges to 1, can we show $F(k)>k^\alpha, \alpha>1$?

Comment: I'd say ratio test converges to $1/\phi < 1$

Comment: @cronos2 : thanks, I must have screwed it up, I try it again

Comment: Fibonacci number grow exponentially, $F_k \approx \frac{\varphi^k}{\sqrt{5}}$ where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(n+1)}<\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{F(n)}{F(n-1)F(n+1)}=\\\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{F(n+1)-F(n-1)}{F(n-1)F(n+1)}=\\\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\Big[\frac{1}{F(n-1)}-\frac{1}{F(n+1)}\Big]=\frac{1}{F(1)}+\frac{1}{F(2)}=2$$

Hence $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F(n)}< 4\space\space\space \blacksquare$$

Comment: I like not using phi, but cant see why the first line is correct?

Comment: @Arjang okk, I am editing it