# Inequality for Fibonacci to find an upper bound of harmonic Fibonacci series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I want to find an sharp upper bound for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}$$which $F_n $ is the n$th$ term of Fibonacci sequence .
I wrote a Matlab program to find an upper bound ,$\sum_{n=1}^{10^6}\frac{1}{F_n}<4$
  Now my question is:(1):Is there an inequality to find this ?
(2): Is that series have a close form ?
$${F_n} = \frac{{{\varphi ^n} - {{( - \varphi )}^{ - n}}}}{{\sqrt 5 }}\to \\\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt 5}{{{\varphi ^n} - {{( - \varphi )}^{ - n}}}}\\\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt 5}{{{(\frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2} ) ^n} }}=\frac{\sqrt5}{1-\frac{1}{\frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2}}}\approx12.18\\$$I am thankful for a hint or solution which can bring a sharper upper bound .

Comment: [maybe related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342940/convergence-of-sum-of-reciprical-of-fibonacci-numbers/2342978#2342978)

Comment: [Simple fast program](https://tio.run/##FYzLCoAgEEXXzldMu5440i6Yj1EQFMqkjOjrbVxcLpz7yF8JZ1prfVIsyGhoHA0RgWUDTnT5mwmKPzIvBt4Qd4/CsGNscAPVTJYCQbVkYmxnWltQdnYSudlODvIVU@mlMdT6Aw): 3.359885666243177553172011302918927179688905133731968486495553815325130318996683383615416216456790087297045342928853913304136789017100883679591351733077119078580333550332507753187599850487179777897006039564509215375892775265673354024033169441799293934610992626257964647651868659449710216558984360881472693249591079473873673378523326877499762727757946853676918541981467668742998767382096913901217722024405208151094264934951

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3.35988566624317755317201130291892717968890513373196848649)
 simply returns ℱ suggesting that it has no closed form.

Comment: @KennyLau:Can I see your program ? can you post it here   ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Just click the link.

Comment: $F_n-\phi^n/\sqrt5=-(-1/\phi)^n/\sqrt5$ has alternating signs. Is it clear that the errors have a sum with the correct sign, and that your inequality follows?

Comment: Compute accurately the sum of the first n terms, and then use crude upper bounds (as you have done) for the sum of the remaining terms.

Comment: Not sure how you got $12.18$ for that value - I got $\approx 5.85$

Answer (score 2):

As Jyrki Lahtonen points out in the comments, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt5}{\varphi^n}$ isn't necessarily the right bound, since it doesn't dominate the original series term-by-term.

As for a closed form, this identity is known:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{F_n}=\frac{\sqrt5}{4}\left(\vartheta_2^2(\varphi^{-2}) + \frac{\log5 + 2\psi_{\varphi^{-4}}(1) - 4\psi_{\varphi^{-2}}(1)}{2\log\varphi}\right)$$
where $\vartheta_2(q)$ is the Jacobi theta function at $z=0$, and $\psi_q$ is the $q$-digamma function. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html) on the "Reciprocal Fibonacci constant", and other Math.SE questions such as [What is the sum of Fibonacci reciprocals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732155/87023)

Comment: $F_n-\phi^n/\sqrt5=-(-1/\phi)^n/\sqrt5$ has alternating signs. Is it clear that the errors have a sum with the correct sign? The OP suffers from the same problem.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Whoops! Let me fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a systematic method for computing upper bounds for the sum without much work.

By induction,
if $F_N \ge b^N$ and $b+1 \ge b^2$, then 
$F_n \ge b^n$ for $n \ge N$.

Therefore, 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over F_n}
\le
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} {1\over F_n}
+
\sum_{n=N}^\infty {1\over b^n}
=
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} {1\over F_n}
+
\frac{1}{b^{N-1}(b-1)}
$$
This upper bound gets closer to the actual sum when $b$ gets larger, but then we need larger $N$:

\begin{array}{crl}
b &N &sum \\
1.3 &4 &4.0172204521317 \\
4/3 &5 &3.7825520833333 \\
1.4 &6 &3.4981694135380 \\
1.5 &11 &3.3651521005948 \\
1.6 &72 &3.3598856662432 \\
\end{array}

Since $1.6 \approx \phi$, which is the largest possible $b$, the last value is quite close to the [actual value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant):
$$
3.359885666243177553172011302918927179688905133732\cdots
$$

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2766491/589

Answer (score 0):

Using Wolfram Mathematica answer is :
[Wolfram Mathematica Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR2dB.png)

[image]