# Evaluate series in terms of the Reciprocal Fibonacci Constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

The Reciprocal Fibonacci Constant $\psi$ is defined as follows:
$$\psi := \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{F_k}$$
where $F_k$ is the kth Fibonacci number, with $F_1=F_2=1$. I would like to know how (if possible) to evaluate one or more of the following infinite series in terms of $\psi$:
$$S_1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{F_k}$$
$$S_2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^kF_k}$$
$$S_3=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{F_k^2}$$
So far, I've determined that
$$S_1+\psi=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{F_{2k}}$$
But I haven't been able to evaluate the sum on the RHS.

Comment: Note that the first series appeared in this question but did not receive any answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421901/alternating-series-and-reciprocal-fibonacci-constant?rq=1

Comment: See Bentin’s answer for the first part here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145285/use-of-the-reciprocal-fibonacci-constant?rq=1

Comment: It might be useful to run the Ferguson-Forcade algorithm (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerRelation.html) in order to understand if the problem actually makes sense or not. I would equally believe that $\psi, S_1, S_2, S_3$ are algebraically independent.